# Hazelcast Replication?

Tags: hazelcast

Does Hazelcast have Replication similar to Ehcache ?
http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/pdf/Ehcache_Replication_Guide.pdf

I've found only Distributed, but not replicated.

Answer (score 7):

If you have N hazelcast instances clustered together (N nodes), then your data will be partitioned in N parts. Each part will be owned by one node. Based on what is the configured replication factor ( default 3) each part will also be replicated in some other nodes. So each node will have a part that it own, and some other parts which are just replica.

Answer (score 3):

See the ReplicatedMap (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#replicated-map) which is best effort replicated and therefore pretty much the equivalent to the replication in EHcache.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, aside from the replicated data structures, there is a way of dynamic replication according to your needs. This is not an official way, just a workaround. You can use backups to make your life easier.

Example:
I have an IMap and I want it in all my nodes (I don't know why you would want that, but let's say you do). I can do 2 steps.

1. backup-count = (NumberOfNodes - 1)
2. read-backup-data = true

So now all your nodes have a copy of the data and since you can read from the backups it's like a replicated map.

You can play with the backup-count or with the async-backup-count depending on the consistency level you want. Click [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#enabling-backup-reads) for more details.

Comment: But not all operations support read-from-backup (anything related to non-key based access), therefore this is often misleading :)

Comment: Yes this is not a good solution. It is a workaround for a read intensive system that has a lot of key related gets. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast's replicated maps are far superior to EHcache's, they will replicate the entire map across every node (JVM) in your cluster.

On top of that you can use a partitioned map which will split your data across all the JVMs but appear to the client as if it is a single map.

This allows you to store much more data than can be stored in a single JVM.

A good rule of thumb for sizing the heap size your cluster is that you get 1/3 for data, 1/3 for backup of another node (assuming backup count is 1) and 1/3 for JVM processing.

Comment: Um, no. OP is asking about replication, and very specifically said that he's not talking about distribution, and you are now explaining distribution. -1.